# Ruby, query active model dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an Order model in my ruby on rails application which has several attributes. I want to query those orders according to parameters given by users such as itemCount, totalPrice and created date.

If one of those attributes is given, I mean it's not nil, I need to query model by using it.

I can do something like:

```
if params[:totalPrice] and params[:itemCount] and params[:created_date]
    @product = Product.where(totalPrice: params[:totalPrice],itemCount: params[:itemCount],created_date: params[:created_date])  
elsif params[:totalPrice] and params[:itemCount]
    @product = Product.where(totalPrice: params[:totalPrice],itemCount: params[:itemCount])
elsif params[:totalPrice] and params[:created_date]
    @product = Product.where(totalPrice: params[:totalPrice],created_date: params[:created_date])  
elsif params[:itemCount] and params[:created_date]
    @product = Product.where(itemCount: params[:itemCount],created_date: params[:created_date]) 
elseif ....(and continues)
```

However, I can't be sure about that. Maybe there is there a "Ruby" way to achieve that problem.

What is the best practice to do that,

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate but close enough IMO.

Answer (score 5):

You can chain the different scopes with ActiveRecord:

```
@products = Product.all
@products = @products.where(totalPrice: params[:totalPrice]) if params[:totalPrice]
@products = @products.where(itemCount: params[:itemCount]) if params[:itemCount]
@products = @products.where(created_date: params[:created_date]) if params[:created_date]
# etc...
```

And this can easily be dynamic (but white-listed):

```
filterable_columns = %i(itemCount totalPrice created_date)
@products = Product.all
filterable_columns.each do |column|
  @products = @products.where(column => params[column]) if params[column]
end
```

Comment: That seem to be great, at least according to my if-else solution. Can I use will-paginate gem with your chain-based solution ?

Comment: yes, ActiveRecord::Relation (returned by the `where` calls basically) allows you to do chain scoping, by either calling several `scope`s defined in your model or your own custom `where` (like I did in this answer). will-paginate works with either a AR::Relation or an array if I recall correctly.